# Bootstrap-3 Carousel freezes after some clicks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, carousel

So I have this carousel in my home. I didn't do any specific config for the bootstrap carousel. I just left it with the default value. I don't initialize it in the JS.

Video :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zMANI5AWab1xO74kQbb4Rq8fRyvkMMNC/view?usp=sharing

So, it's working normally sometimes. But there is a case that happen randomly that the carousel freezes. After doing some research, turned out that the class of the carousel didn't change (see the video).

When I clicked the arrow, the carousel change the siblings of the .active class to .next.left then after that, the .next became the .active.

But sometimes it's stuck, and not changing. That's when it freezes.
And it's random, sometime even the second time click is already freezes.

But sometime, it took like 50+ clicks to get the error.

I've tried to research it and some of the forums here suggest to rearrange the script. I tried to load jquery first then bootstrap.js. But the freezes still occurs.

It should be running without problem and always responsive to the click.

Here's the code

```
 <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container"> 
      <div id="banner-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#banner-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#banner-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#banner-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <h1>First</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h1>Second</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <h1>Third</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#banner-carousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#banner-carousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Update**: 
I've researched here and there, and there's one way that make it works.

https://gist.github.com/jonraasch/373874#file-jquery-support-transition-js

By adding that line, it works, but in logged some console error everytime it slides.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: kindly share your exact code so that we can see if the issue replicates or not...

Comment: The culprit was $.support.transition. I ended up creating a function to replace the value.

function getSupport() {
  const thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement;
  const thisStyle = thisBody.style;
  if (thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined) {
    return 'mozTransition';
  } else if (thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined) {
    return 'msTransition';
  } else if (thisStyle.oTransition !== undefined) {
    return 'oTransition';
  } else if (thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined) {
    return 'webkitTransition';
  }
  return 'transition';
}